# Web scraping the second of two tables on a page in Python 3 with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm working on my python skills and I'm trying to scrape only the "Results" table from this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Wales_national_rugby_union_team_results . I'm new to web scraping, could anyone help me with an elegant solution for scraping the Results wikitable? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use Pandas to load the tables:

```
import pandas as pd

tables = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Wales_national_rugby_union_team_results')

# print second table (index 1):
print(tables[1])
```

Prints:

```
                 Date                 Venue Home team   Away team       Score                     Competition    Winner Match report
0        7 March 2020    Twickenham Stadium   England       Wales       33–30                2020 Six Nations   England          BBC
1    22 February 2020  Principality Stadium     Wales      France       23–27                2020 Six Nations    France          BBC
2     8 February 2020         Aviva Stadium   Ireland       Wales       24–14                2020 Six Nations   Ireland          BBC
3     1 February 2020  Principality Stadium     Wales       Italy        42–0                2020 Six Nations     Wales          BBC
4    30 November 2019  Principality Stadium     Wales  Barbarians       43–33                      Tour Match     Wales          BBC
..                ...                   ...       ...         ...         ...                             ...       ...          ...
741    5 January 1884       Cardigan Fields   England       Wales    1G 2T–1G  1884 Home Nations Championship   England          NaN
742    8 January 1883         Raeburn Place  Scotland       Wales       3G–1G  1883 Home Nations Championship  Scotland          NaN
743  16 December 1882            St Helen's     Wales     England     0–2G 4T  1883 Home Nations Championship   England          NaN
744   28 January 1882        Lansdowne Road   Ireland       Wales     0–2G 2T                             NaN     Wales          NaN
745  19 February 1881    Richardson's Field   England       Wales  7G 6T 1D–0                             NaN   England          NaN

[746 rows x 8 columns]
```